# Reuse an object created in a function in R

Tags: r, function

I have searched SO and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994368/r-2-15-2-how-to-make-object-created-within-function-usable-outside), but I still can't get it to work.

I am rather new to R programming, so I appreciate this help.

Suppose I have a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(State = c("NJ", "MA", "CA", "CA", "MA"), 
                 Sales = c(15, 100, 30, 56, 60), 
                 Price = c(34, 52, 21, NA, 20), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now I want a function that creates a new `data.frame` that just has a given state... So I wrote:

```
state_function <- function(state) {
        #Subset the rows in the state from all rows
        new_df <- df[df[,"State"] == state, ]
         ## I will do many other things inside the function ##
        summary(new_df)
        return(new_df)
}

state_function ("NJ")
```

But now I want to re-use this `data.frame`, `new_df` , outside of this function ..(and I want to generalize this example) .. How can I do this? In general, I want to use a object or `data.frame` that I create in a function, outside of a function.

Comment: Just assign it? `new_df <- state_function ("NJ")`

Answer (score 2):

Assign the value to a variable when running the function:

```
new_df <- state_function("NJ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
state_function <- function(state) {

   new_df <- subset(df, State == state)
   print( summary(new_df) )
   new_df

}

new_df <- state_function("CA")
```

Note that we can use the `subset` function to clean up the first line of the body.  Also the `summary` line in the question does nothing without `print`.  Automatic printing does not occur within functions.  Also the `return` is not really needed.  Finally assign the output of the function to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `assign` to assign a global variable within a function.  Be careful though, as `y` will be overwritten each time you run the function.

```
state.function <- function(x, state)
{
    assign('y', subset(x, x$State == state), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    return(y)
}

> state.function(df, "CA")
#   State Sales Price
# 3    CA    30    21
# 4    CA    56    NA
> y
#   State Sales Price
# 3    CA    30    21
# 4    CA    56    NA
```

This works well if you're going through data quickly.  If you remove `return(y)` there will be no output to the function, but the variable `y` will exist in the global environment.  This is sometimes useful.

And if you hate quoting things, like I do

```
state.function <- function(x, state)
{
    z <- deparse(substitute(state))
    assign('y', subset(x, x$State == z), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

> state.function(df, CA)
> y
#   State Sales Price
# 3    CA    30    21
# 4    CA    56    NA
```