# Save dataframes of a certain directory as a dataframes list in the environment with a function (R)

Tags: r, function, dataframe, environment, read.csv

I want to make a function that reads all csv of a local directory and save them as a list of dataframes in my R environment. I tried the follwing:

```
 getdflist <- function(directory = getwd()) {
      setwd(directory)
      monitors <- list.files(directory)
      dataframes <- vector("list", length(monitors))
      for (i in seq_along(monitors)) {
        dataframes[[i]] <- read.csv(monitors[[i]])
        print(i)
      }
      dataframes
}
```

but it only prints i and doesn't save the list in my environment

Could anyone help me to see the error on my code?

Note: When I try to run it as a code (not a function):

```
> monitors <-list.files(getwd())
> dataframes <- vector("list", length(monitors))
> for (i in 1:length(monitors)){
+     dataframes[[i]] <- read.csv(monitors[[i]], sep = ",")
+ }
>
```

it works and saves it as a dataframes list with 65.5MB weight, the problem is when I pass it as a function. May be it could be because the lexical scoping?

Solution for this question is the most valued answer for this: [How to make object created within function usable outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994368/how-to-make-object-created-within-function-usable-outside)

Comment: Your function returns nothing. After the `for` loop write `dataframes` as the last instruction of the function. Also, instead of `dataframes <- list(...)` before the loop, it would be much better `dataframes <- vector("list", length = length(monitors))`.

Comment: Why it doesn't return nothing if I have already created the dataframes object? I mean, It would overwrite each element of dataframes with the resulting dataframe of apply read.csv function, wouldn't it?

Comment: It doesn't return the `dataframes` object because you are forgetting my first suggestion in the comment above: ***the last instruction of a function is its return value.*** So you need to write just `dataframes` as the last line of the function. I will now edit your code

Comment: Rui Brradas thanks for help, but my problem was other, the solution is in a link to other question in my new edition of this quiestion, sorry for not was able to explain myself.

Answer (score 3):

```
setwd("directory")
dfs = list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
getdflist <- lapply(dfs, read.csv)
names(getdflist) <- dfs
```

Comment: It's a good Idea to use lapply, but it keeps not saving the list in my R environment.

Comment: Two notes: 1) you don't need to create `getdflist <- list()`, `lapply` will do it for you; 2) instead of `read.table` use `read.csv`, it's the **same** function with some arguments set, such as `sep = ",", header = TRUE`. Anyway, upvote

Comment: @RuiBarradas has it may be to do with lexical scoping? Because I don't understand why it works if I run it as a code but not as a function.