# How to number/label data-table by group-number from group_by?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, indices

I have a tbl_df where I want to `group_by(u, v)` for each distinct integer combination observed with `(u, v)`.

---

**EDIT:** this was subsequently resolved by adding the (now-deprecated) `group_indices()` back in [dplyr 0.4.0](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/releases)

---

a) I then want to assign each distinct group some arbitrary distinct number label=1,2,3...
e.g. the combination (u,v)==(2,3) could get label 1, (1,3) could get 2, and so on.
How to do this with one `mutate()`, without a three-step summarize-and-self-join?

dplyr has a neat function `n()`, but that gives the number of elements **within** its group, not the overall **number of the group**. [In `data.table` this would simply be called `.GRP`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf).

b) Actually what I really want to assign a string/character label ('A','B',...).
But numbering groups by integers is good-enough, because I can then use `integer_to_label(i)` as below. Unless there's a clever way to merge these two? But don't sweat this part.

```
set.seed(1234)

# Helper fn for mapping integer 1..26 to character label
integer_to_label <- function(i) { substr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",i,i) }

df <- tibble::as_tibble(data.frame(u=sample.int(3,10,replace=T), v=sample.int(4,10,replace=T)))

# Want to label/number each distinct group of unique (u,v) combinations
df %>% group_by(u,v) %>% mutate(label = n()) # WRONG: n() is number of element within its group, not overall number of group

   u v
1  2 3
2  1 3
3  1 2
4  2 3
5  1 2
6  3 3
7  1 3
8  1 2
9  3 1
10 3 4

KLUDGE 1: could do df %>% group_by(u,v) %>% summarize(label = n()) , then self-join
```

Comment: @Randy-Lai and I both solved it, separately. Randy's is a cleaner idiom that lends itself to multiple `mutate/summarize(...)` actions. I found `interaction(u,v, drop=T)`

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: @hadley: my particular reason is as stated in the question: I want to assign each distinct (u,v)-group some arbitrary (ordered) numbering=1,2,3... so I can ultimately assign them string labels 'A','B','C'... (my purpose is to subsequently refer to them by shorthand, in modeling and graphing)

Comment: @hadley: but in general this is a useful feature, and data.table package implements `.GRP` for this. Any chance we can have something in dplyr please? :)

Comment: next version will have `group_indices()`

Comment: @hadley Thanks! New in [0.4.0 (1/2015)](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/releases)

Comment: @SamFirke: thanks for the updates and answer, but please leave my ancient cave scribblings in the question. Also, don't delete the comparison to `data.table`, that's all useful too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated answer

```
get_group_number = function(){
    i = 0
    function(){
        i <<- i+1
        i
    }
}
group_number = get_group_number()
df %>% group_by(u,v) %>% mutate(label = group_number())
```

You can also consider the following slightly unreadable version

```
group_number = (function(){i = 0; function() i <<- i+1 })()
df %>% group_by(u,v) %>% mutate(label = group_number())
```

---

using `iterators` package

```
library(iterators)

counter = icount()
df %>% group_by(u,v) %>% mutate(label = nextElem(counter))
```

Comment: No, this is wrong. I'm **not** looking for the row-number within a group. I'm looking for the **group-number** (the equivalent of `data.table .GRP`). Since we have 7 unique combinations of (u,v) in this example, the output labels should be 1:7 (in some arbitrary order)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay much attention to your question. I have updated the answer with a dirty solution...

Comment: not bad but that's essentially just a generator function that returns incrementing integers... surely we can obviate it?

Comment: ^ Does R not do generator functions? (like Python `yield`?) Without having to manually save state inside your fn?

Comment: you remind me of `iterators` package. I have never used it before. (And see the updated solution). But it is essentially equivalent to my original method.

Comment: ^ Wow that's awesome! Best answer. Did you see my new one using `interaction(u,v)`? Can you figure out how to reorder the levels in increasing order?

Comment: i think you will get the correct order if you order `df`.

Comment: Assume we want to preserve the order of df (we do, my real case is more complicated). It would be clunky to `dplyr::arrange(u,v)` then do this group-numbering then revert to `dplyr::arrange(<previous-variable-ordering>)`

Comment: may be `factor(interaction(sort(df$u),sort(df$v)))` (I didn't test it).

Comment: Naw... I've been trying many things unsuccessfully for a while now. Might post as a separate question.

Comment: Solved - see my updated answer. And question link below.

Comment: Update: New [group_indices_  in 0.4.0 (1/2015)](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/releases)

Answer (score 55):

**For current dplyr versions (1.0.0 and higher)**

Since version 1.0, dplyr has a new [cur_group_id](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html) function for that:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(u, v) %>% 
    mutate(label = cur_group_id()) ...
```

**For previous dplyr versions (before 1.0.0, although the function is deprecated but still available in 1.0.10)**

dplyr has a `group_indices()` function that you can use like this:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(label = group_indices(., u, v)) %>% 
    group_by(label) ...
```

Comment: group_indices() uses the (alphabetical) ordering of the grouping variable though, is there any way of using it to preserve the ordering in the table, or applying your own?

Comment: Note that `group_indices()` was deprecated in dplyr 1.0.0. and has been replaced with `cur_group_id()`.

Answer (score 11):

Another approach using `data.table` would be

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[,label:=.GRP, by = c("u", "v")]
```

which results in:

```
    u v label
 1: 2 1     1
 2: 1 3     2
 3: 2 1     1
 4: 3 4     3
 5: 3 1     4
 6: 1 1     5
 7: 3 2     6
 8: 2 3     7
 9: 3 2     6
10: 3 4     3
```

Answer (score 9):

As of dplyr version 1.0.4, the function `cur_group_id()` has replaced the older function `group_indices`.

Call it on the grouped data.frame:

```
df %>%
  group_by(u, v) %>%
  mutate(label = cur_group_id())

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   u, v [6]
       u     v label
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     2     2     4
 2     2     2     4
 3     1     3     2
 4     3     2     6
 5     1     4     3
 6     1     2     1
 7     2     2     4
 8     2     4     5
 9     3     2     6
10     2     4     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating my answer with three different ways:

A) A neat non-dplyr solution using `interaction(u,v)`:

```
> df$label <- factor(interaction(df$u,df$v, drop=T))
 [1] 1.3 2.3 2.2 2.4 3.2 2.4 1.2 1.2 2.1 2.1
 Levels: 2.1 1.2 2.2 3.2 1.3 2.3 2.4

> match(df$label, levels(df$label)[ rank(unique(df$label)) ] )
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 4 6 6 7 7
```

B) Making Randy's neat fast-and-dirty generator-function answer more compact:

```
get_next_integer = function(){
  i = 0
  function(u,v){ i <<- i+1 }
}
get_integer = get_next_integer() 

df %>% group_by(u,v) %>% mutate(label = get_integer())
```

---

C) Also here is a one-liner using a generator function abusing a global variable assignment from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726705/assign-multiple-objects-to-globalenv-from-within-a-function):

```
i <- 0
generate_integer <- function() { return(assign('i', i+1, envir = .GlobalEnv)) }

df %>% group_by(u,v) %>% mutate(label = generate_integer())

rm(i)
```

Comment: The reason that I used `get_group_name` is to avoid using global variable. I think it is in general not a good idea to change global variables inside a function...but it works anyway.

Comment: I compacted yours and put it at the top of my answer. An assignment evaluates to its LHS value, hence we can simply say `function(u,v){ i <<- i+1 }`

Comment: I also found a neat three-liner non-dplyr way with `interaction(u,v)`, and added that at top.

Comment: I also solved the incremental-order issue with `interaction(... drop=T)` per [this subquestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028406/how-to-reorder-arbitrary-integer-vector-to-be-in-increasing-order)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation for a comment, so I'm posting an answer instead.

The solution using factor() is a good one, but it has the disadvantage that group numbers are assigned after factor() alphabetizes its levels. The same behaviour happens with dplyr's group_indices(). Perhaps you would like the group numbers to be assigned from 1 to n based on the current group order. In which case, you can use:

```
my_tibble %>% mutate(group_num = as.integer(factor(group_var, levels = unique(.$group_var))) )
```

Comment: Thanks. As I noted in the question, this was all solved by adding `group_indices()` back in dplyr 0.4.0 in 2015