# Incremental IDs in a R data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
> test = data.frame(A = sample(1:5, 10, replace = T)) %>% arrange(A)
> test

   A
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  2
5  2
6  2
7  2
8  4
9  4
10 5
```

I now want every row to have an ID that is only incremented when the value of A changes. This is what I have tried:

```
> test = test %>% mutate(id = as.numeric(rownames(test))) %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(id = min(id))
> test

       A    id
   (int) (dbl)
1      1     1
2      1     1
3      1     1
4      2     4
5      2     4
6      2     4
7      2     4
8      4     8
9      4     8
10     5    10
```

However, I would like to get the following:

```
       A    id
   (int) (dbl)
1      1     1
2      1     1
3      1     1
4      2     2
5      2     2
6      2     2
7      2     2
8      4     3
9      4     3
10     5     4
```

Comment: Is your A column always increasing? Does "when the value of A changes" mean that for A = 3 3 4 3, you want 1 1 2 3, for example?

Comment: Initially, my A column is unsorted, but I will sort it before assigning the IDs. So A = 3 3 4 3 should be 1 1 2 1 because I will sort it to be A = 3 3 3 4

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. Let us know if the linked question (in a banner at the top, if you refresh the page) doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% mutate(id = dense_rank(A))
```

Answer (score 5):

One compact option would be using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(test)`), grouped by 'A', we assign (`:=`) `.GRP` as the new 'id' column.  The `.GRP` will be a sequence of values for each unique value in 'A'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, id:=.GRP, A]
```

In case the value of 'A' changes like `3, 3, 4, 3` and we want `1, 1, 2, 3` forthe 'id'

```
setDT(test)[, id:= rleid(A)]
```

---

Or we convert 'A' to `factor` class and then coerce it back to `numeric/integer`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
    mutate(id = as.integer(factor(A)))
```

Or we can `match` 'A' with the `unique` values in 'A'.

```
test %>%
     mutate(id = match(A, unique(A)))
```

---

Or from the `dplyr` version > `0.4.0`, we can use `group_indices` (it is in the dupe link)

```
test %>%
      mutate(id=group_indices_(test, .dots= "A"))
```

Comment: Dplyr has `group_indices` to go with data.table's `.GRP`. I recall it being buggy, though. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23026145/1191259

Comment: @Frank Looks like the `group_indices` is not working with `dplyr_0.4.3`

Comment: @Frank If I use `test %>% group_indices(A)` it gives a vector.

Comment: You should add some of these solutions to the linked question?

Comment: @Frank Never mind, it works

Comment: @PierreLafortune  You are welcome to add there, thanks ..

Comment: How do I go about this if I need incremental ids within each group. For example, {A: group1, group2, group2, group1, group2, group3, group2}, and the corresponding values in the second column are {id: 1,1,2,2,3,1,4}? I can write nested for loops for this, but is there a better way?

Comment: @vipin8169  Please do ask as a new question

Comment: I did, and got my answer as well. Thanks