# Autoincrement variable name in R loop

Tags: r, variables

I'm trying to create a function, which creates n variables named automatically x1, x2, ..., xn. I have an approach, which works only through the console and not in a function (the runif creates an array of 1000 numbers between -1 and 1, which should be assigned to the variable):

```
for(i in 1:n) {
   assign(sprintf("x%d",i),runif(1000,min=-1,max=1))
}
```

When I use it in a function, no variables are created in the environment...

I tried to make something like this:

```
for(i in 1:n) {
   sprintf("x%d",i) <- runif(1000,min=-1,max=1))
}
```

But this returns the error *"target of assignment expands to non-language object"*. Also tried to use as.name(), eval(), aso. But I didn't get the list of the variables x1 to xn in my environment through a function.

Could someone give me a hint? Thx a lot in advance!

Comment: I think the first example does create the variables. Have you checked your environment using `ls()` ?

Comment: There is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726705/assign-multiple-objects-to-globalenv-from-within-a-function you just need to specify the environment. But it comes with lots of commentary that says "Don't do this at home". Is there any reason you can't have the function return a list or vector?

Comment: I'd recommend reading my answer to [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061), I include a good bit of information of why this is Bad. Just use a list instead, make life easy.

Comment: How to use a list in this case: `xlist = replicate(n, runif(1000, min = -1, max = 1), simplify = FALSE)`. Then use `x[[1]]`, `x[[5]]`, etc.

Comment: Thx for all the useful comments! I will start to work with lists and matrixes.
@phoxis I do work with RStudio, so I always have the environment visible in the specific frame.

Comment: In that case, it looks like you are generating this in a local scope. Better make a dataframe and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to create `n` different variable? The `R` way is to create a `matrix` or `data.frame` and play with it. If this is really 1000 variables that you need , then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1236620/9670603) gives:

```r
f<-function(n)for(i in 1:n){
    assign(sprintf("x%d",i),runif(1000,min=-1,max=1),envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
f(10)
x5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpNCsIwEAbQfU4xFIQMpJIs3IhZFs8RfyID7ReZtCUgnj3iWz/tPV/GvOG@SoEF56JWSEDhDP4YIkq1ygu2vlWwZju0w2Nwwk43SLbBe@8WQRyDW1KLgd0TuyhFOl7nckvzhJ3N1/wrm3Yyvf8A)

but you really should do:

```r
f<-function(n){
x <- matrix(runif(1000*n),ncol=n)
colnames(x) <-paste0(rep("x",n),1:n)
x
}
f(10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCoAgEEDR/ZwiXM1Egm2jDiOhIOQUpjAQnd2m1d@8X3qPq42N95pORqYHZFjtkH0tSbA0ThFn59zINPF@HhsTaNjncKOQ2svfNTgs4UIjZlI3L4oEXvhX6v0D)

Comment: Thanks a lot, wasn't aware of the possibility to work with a matrix (I'm a R-noob :))... I have an assignment where I have to create 100 progressions of 1000 variables and add them to create a normal distribution...

Comment: Just checked this way as a function in RStudio...also didn't get the matrix in the environment. Maybe I have to add the `envir` argument?

Comment: You have to assign the result of the function. Try `m <- f(100)` and you should see `m`. If this works for you don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: thx, no idea why I didn't get this one :) just had to put a simple return(...) and then the direct assignement!