# simplifying creating multiple world raster in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, raster

can I simplify this using a loop? I need to make over 50 of them and I am currently doing it manually (e.g., r, r1, r2, r3, r4 ...).

Is there a way I can do all 50 in a simpler code?

```
r   <- raster(extent(-180, 180, -90, 90), ncols = 150, nrows = 80)
r1  <- raster(extent(-180, 180, -90, 90), ncols = 150, nrows = 80)
r2  <- raster(extent(-180, 180, -90, 90), ncols = 150, nrows = 80)
```

Comment: Is it help? https://www.w3schools.com/r/r_for_loop.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can map the function `assign` on a sequence:

```
library(raster)
library(purrr)

my_raster <- raster(extent(-180, 180, -90, 90), ncols = 150, nrows = 80)

seq(50) %>% 
  walk(~ assign(x = paste0("r", .x), my_raster, envir = globalenv()))
```

Please keep in mind that this will mess up your global environment quite much. It is much cleaner to group the rasters into one `list`:

```
my_rasters <-
  seq(50) %>%
  map(~ paste0("my_raster_", .x)) %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map(~my_raster)

# access one raster
my_rasters$my_raster_23
```

Comment: what do you mean by ```list```? what does envir = globalenv() do? I tried to look it up but there is this discussion that says not to use it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726705/assign-multiple-objects-to-globalenv-from-within-a-function

Comment: Values are stored in buckets called environments. If you need to access them from everywhere without defining the env explicitly, you need to create them in the global env. I added a statement about messyness in my answer. Creating global vars will have side effects so things get complicated.

Comment: how do I group them by ```list```? is this different?

Comment: Use `map` instead of `walk`: `my_rasters <- seq(50) %>% map(~ my_raster)` Note that the function `rep`  only works for S3 objects.

Comment: is it possible to rename them so the output is my_raster1, my_raster_2 etc. this comes as [[1]]

Comment: @L55 Yes: I updated my answer accordingly.